# How iterate over wp options list output using bash?

Tags: bash, wp-cli

I want to create a script that adds WordPress options in a fresh WordPress installation using WP-CLI.

I ran this command `wp option list --format=json | jq -c -M  '.[]'`

The output of the command like this:

```sh
{"option_name":"siteurl","option_value":"http://wp.test"}
{"option_name":"home","option_value":"http://wp.test"}
```

So how to iterate over each object and run `add` command and passing `key` and `value` as an argument like this `wp option add $option_name $option_value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach: Use `jq` to build the `wp` commands and execute them in your shell:

```sh
source <(wp option list --format=json |
         jq -r '.[] | "wp option add \"\(.option_name)\" \"\(.option_value)\""')
```